# Запуск loader пока грузиться страница

Tags: javascript

Как сделать loader на сайте? Отправляется запрос через AJAX, далее пока грузит вывод, показываем loader, ну типа картинка загрузки.
Не знаю как правильно в поисковике найти

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, можно так, в beforeSend - показываем лоадер, в сomplete прячем(jquery):

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "...",
   datatype: "json",
   cache: false,
   async: true,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   method: "POST",
   data: JSON.stringify({ ...  }),
   beforeSend: function () {                          
     $("#loader").show();                           
   },
   complete: function () {                                                    
     $("#loader").hide();                                              
   },
   success: function (data, textStatus) {
     // ...                              
   } 
});
```